# Robo framework test fails when try to import other module in test or keyword file

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to set up custom test library and user keyword using robot framework.

I created my test file or userkeyword file as below hello.py.

please look at the import statement in the hello.py.

> if i comment out import statement(import
>   src.factory.serverconnectfactory) and run - test case is PASS **
>
> if i uncomment import statement - test case is FAIL. don't know why it
>   fails ?

I did try to google a lot did not find any clue , even read the user guide of robot framework 
not able to get any clue.

How can I import src.factory.serverconnectfactory and use it in hello.py ?

example : hello.py

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
# import src.factory.serverconnectfactory ---- this line is the issue

class helloworld:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @keyword("print hello")
    def printhelloworld(self):
        return "Hello World"
```

my robot test file

```
****** Settings ***
Library   ..//..//keywordslib//helloworld.py

*** Test Cases ***
This is some test case
   print hello
```

the error i use to get is

```
> Importing test library failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
```

thanks in advance.

Solution :

> Robot Framework expects Filename and classname to be same

Comment: How does it fail? What is the error message? Also, you shouldn't be using `/` in a file path. A single `/' is sufficient.

Comment: @BryanOakley found the solution for some reason Robot framework expects filename and class name to be same.  I use "//" escape character or else import library do not work.

Comment: `/` is not an escape character. It's just a normal character. The escape character is `\`. `/` and `\` are not the same thing.